# oracle-maven-sync plugin (v14.1.1) error while deploying web application: 'deploy' goal not found

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, weblogic

I am using following plugin to deploy my web application to weblogic 14c with maven (3.6.3):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-maven-sync</artifactId>
            <version>14.1.1-0-0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wls-deploy</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                        <user>weblogic</user>
                        <password>weblogic123</password>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                        <targets>AdminServer</targets>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

while executing the goal, maven is giving the below error:

> [ERROR] Could not find goal 'deploy' in plugin
> com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:14.1.1-0-0 among available goals
> help, push -> [Help 1]

Eclipse also giving the below warning for the pom file having plugin configuration:

> Invalid goal for this plugin: deploy

any clue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you should use the `weblogic-maven-plugin` instead.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wlprg/maven.html#GUID-1E101A83-0099-4089-A9EE-3999F2C8D84C.

Comment: Catch was changing the artifactid from oracle-maven-sync to weblogic-maven-plugin